# Why does the Θ-class survive adding a constant only for positive, monotonic, and non-decreasing functions?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I know that for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions, f(n) and g(n),

```
f(n) = O(g(n) + c) entails
f (n) = O(g(n))
```

Why is this always true only for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions? $\Theta$

If there exists one, give a counter-example that shows that the above Big O rule is not necessarily true for functions that are *not* monotonically non-decreasing.

I'm really confused why the rule specifies only positive, monotonic, non-decreasing functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: General note: The mere fact that you have a theorem $A \implies B$ does *not* imply that $\lnot A \implies \lnot B$ (which you seem to be assuming). Maybe we were just not able to prove more even though it's true, or we didn't bother. And there *certainly* may be examples for which the rule holds but which don't collectively have a nice characterisation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n) = 1-1/n$ and $g(n) = 1/n$, so we've violated the condition that $g$ is non-decreasing. However, it's not hard to show that $f(n) \in O(g(n)+2)$ but we also have $f(n)\notin O(g(n)$, invalidating the inference.

Comment: but isn't f(n) = 1 - 1/n a monotonically non-decreasing function? Is there an example that is not monotonically non-decreasing?

Comment: oh ok, so 1-1/n is monotonic but not non-decreasing. got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $f(n) = O(g(n)+h(n))$ and $g(n) = \Omega(h(n))$ then $f(n) = O(g(n))$. If, on the contrary, $g(n) = o(h(n))$, then $f(n) = O(h(n))$. (It could also be that neither conditions hold.)